# How to add Base class in Master Page for Multilingual Site

Tags: asp.net

I have got site for multilingual. I have added Resources file for it. But I have problem in Master Page.

I have added Base class which have `InitializeCulture()` method. This Class inherit from content page. So all content page text have been changed according to language selection. But problem in master page Because when I inherit base class from master page error showing that Master Page does contain defination for Intializeculture.

Base Class Method is:

```
protected override void InitializeCulture()
{   
    if (Session["myapplication.language"] != null)
    {
        string selectedLanguage = Session["myapplication.language"] as string;

        Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture(selectedLanguage);        
        Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = new CultureInfo(selectedLanguage);
    }
}
```

I also added this method in `Page_Init` event of Master Page. But no result found.